# On form submit redirect to the same page(based on active class)

Tags: php, html

I have 5 menu in my page,first time when login its redirecting to my dashboard, the #menu1(ABOUT) is the my current class, its fine but i have #menu4(CONTACT) where i have one html form and in form submit it must redirect to the same menu but the problem after submitting the form its going back to 1st menu(ABOUT) because 1st menu is the active class.

So how to make my The menu(CONTACT) is also active, means if user submit the form it must be in the same page/menu,it should not redirect to the 1st menu(CONTACT)

```html
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">home</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">test</a></li>
                        <li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4" >CONTACT</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3" >Analytics</a></li>
                     </ul>
```

Comment: provide pls your contact form and you files stricture

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  var Location = $(location). attr("href");
  Location += $('.nav li.active a').attr('href');
  window.location.href = "Location";
});
```

Html:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="sub"  value="Enter">
</form>
```

> you can try `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` in action and add `active` class on menu, if possible

Comment: ,is 'form ' is the id of submit button or form?

Comment: Khandelewal,thnaks for reply ,i am doing this in laraval,so my form action is action="{{ url('/dashboard') }}" so how to pass href in jquery attr,if any idea pls share?

Comment: ok,i am using the same code and even same ul nav,but after submitting the form its going back to 1st menu,but i need the page must be redirect to same menu box,i am sending data through post,is thats cereating the problem??

Comment: removed action="{{url('/dashboard')}}",form is submitting but redirecting back to 1st menu

Comment: no,active class is added in 1st menu page,and form is in 4th menu,hear active class is not added,bec 1st time when user come to page the 1st menu is active then he will go th 4th menu ,submit the form then it must be redirect there(4th menu),not in first menu where we already added the active class

Comment: this is the 4th menu <div id="menu4" class="tab-pane fade ">
                            <div>
                                <form id="menu-form" class="form-horizontal" method="get" form action="{{url('/#menu4')}}" accept-charset="UTF-8">...html code</form></div>

Comment: so u mean action="{{url('/#menu4')}}"   like this i need to add action?

Comment: check updated answer or try to send form using `Ajax`